# Parasyte anime 20 years after the manga finished - Why?

Tags: anime-production, parasyte

My question is Why?

Most manga that have anime adaptions get them while they are still on-going (even if the manga ends during the initial anime run.)

Can anyone give/think of a reason why they suddenly made this after 20 years?

**Edit:** Glad they did though, its might be my favourite anime.

Comment: I looked at Hitoshi Iwaaki's (the mangaka of Parasyte) Wikipedia page and none of his works had been adapted into an anime. Maybe he wasn't a "hot" mangaka back then and the fact that hidden gems such as Parasyte got discovered and animated probably means that his other works (Historie comes to my mind) may also receive the same treatment in the near future.

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi I've removed your comment because it didn't add anything relevant to the discussion (not to say your opinion isn't relevant, but to the point in question no value was added by it), and contained massive spoilers for viewers/readers.

Answer (score 1):

Because they felt like it. Simple as that. Though the Parasyte Live action movies have been in development hell for years, so the anime might have simply been a marketing tool to get people interested in the movies since the Manga is pretty old, and even the reprint edition (from 2006 or so) can be kind of hard to find.